# Clojure: Wrong number of args (4) passed to: core$rest

Tags: clojure

> Write a function which allows you to create function compositions. The
>   parameter list should take a variable number of functions, and create
>   a function applies them from right-to-left.

```
(fn [& fs]
  (fn [& args]
    (->> (reverse fs)
         (reduce #(apply %2 %1) args))))
```

http://www.4clojure.com/problem/58

```
=> (= [3 2 1] ((_ rest reverse) [1 2 3 4]))

clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (4) passed to: core$rest
```

What's causing this error? I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in your use of `apply` - this turns the last parameter into a flattened list of parameters, creating a call that looks like:

`(rest 1 2 3 4)`

Which is presumably not what you intended..... and explains the error you are getting.